# i can not find the error comming from this massage (TypeError: module() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)) when i run the following code

Tags: tensorflow, class, keras, layer

#this is my code and i didn't know what's the rong
#i need your help please

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers
class AE(layers):
def __init__(self):
    super(AE, self).__init__()
    
    self.fc1 = layers.Dense(16,activation='relu',input_dim=16)
    self.fc2 = layers.Dense(7,activation='linear')
    self.fc3 = layers.BatchNormalization()
    self.fc4 = layers.GaussianNoise(stddev,name='noise')
    self.fc5 = layers.Dense(16,activation='relu')
    self.fc6 = layers.Dense(16,activation='softmax')
```

Answer (score 0):

`class AE(layers):` is trying to inherit from the `layers` module, not the `layers.Layer` class.

Replace `class AE(layers):` with `class AE(layers.Layer):` as follows to solve the error.

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers
#class AE(layers):
class AE(layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self):
    super(AE, self).__init__()
    
    self.fc1 = layers.Dense(16,activation='relu',input_dim=16)
    self.fc2 = layers.Dense(7,activation='linear')
    self.fc3 = layers.BatchNormalization()
    self.fc4 = layers.GaussianNoise(stddev,name='noise')
    self.fc5 = layers.Dense(16,activation='relu')
    self.fc6 = layers.Dense(16,activation='softmax')
```